# R conditionally bind rows in loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, double, rbind

I have a double for loop over a data frame and its rows. I'm applying some calculations for each row of the data frame (which represent different batteries and therefore all vary in their values). In the end I want to check if a row (e.g. a battery) fits the criteria. If it does, I want to put it in a new df gathering all batteries that fit the criteria.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix("values",nrow=24,ncol=19))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix("values",nrow=2976,ncol=22))
df3 <- df1[0,] #empty df of the same structure as df1
```

What I'm doing:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){

# some calculations giving me a result what the necessary capacity "nc" is
...
```

so far it works alright. What I want to do then is compare if the result for each row in in df1 (e.g. the necessary battery capacity) is bigger then a condition "con":

```
...
con <- df1[i,4]
nc <- max(df2[[20]])) # defining the necessary capacity
  if(con > nc){
   newdf <- bind_rows(df3,df1[i,])
  }
 } 
}
```

I expect newdf to have 0 to max 24 rows. According to the real data I should get 11 entries. What I got was 1 (that was the last row of df1) or some more than 30000 entries. So this is not working as expected. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You'd get help faster if you shared some dummy data rather than "dummy" data. Also, I have a feeling you may not even need 2 for-loops.

Comment: R is a vectorized language, you don't need a loop to create a new dataframe, just make perform the filter and assign to a new df: `newdf<-df[df[,4] > nc, ]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to increment `df3` and this is why you only have one line, you always bind one row to the empty `df3` `data.frame`. Your code works otherwise. You should change the line

```
newdf <- bind_rows(df3,df1[i,])
```

into

```
df3 <- bind_rows(df3,df1[i,])
```

This might be very slow however, so I suggest you use vectorization, for example as suggested in the comments by @Dave2i `newdf<-df[df[,4] > nc, ]`